# If method in module B takes class from module A is it necessary to import module A in module B?

Tags: python, python-import

Say `moduleA.py` contains

```
class Square:
    def __init__(self, length)
        self.length = length
```

and `moduleB.py` contains

```
def scale_shape(shape, scale_factor):
    shape.width = scale_factor*shape.width
```

Say `moduleA` imports `moduleB` and implements the `scale_shape` function. Alternatively there might be a `moduleC` which imports both `moduleA` and `moduleB` which implements both `square` and `scale_shape`.

We see that the function/method in `moduleB.py` takes an object of type `square` but doesn't require direct access to that class since it doesn't instantiate any `square`s. It only uses the class implicitly somehow.

Is it required or best practice to import `moduleA` within `moduleB`?

Comment: You shouldn't have to unless you add a type hint for `square` (which should be [`class Square:`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names)) but also consider putting both code snippets in the same module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Best practice is to only import what you need.**

`ModuleC` would not need to import `Square` in order to use `scale_shape`. What's more, `scale_shape`, doesn't type check, and would happily take any object with a `width` attribute.

If is it important to you that `scale_shape` only takes in shapes, type check:

```
from ModuleA import Square    

def scale_shape(shape, scale_factor):
    assert isinstance(shape, Square)
    shape.width = scale_factor*shape.width
```